# What is the unit of smoothing in gdal_grid?

Tags: raster, gdal

I am using the `gdal_grid` command line with `invdist` algorithm and would like to spedify a smoothing parameter but I am wondering whether it shouold be in pixel or data units (meters in my case)?

I've found the following related links :

- [gdal_grid](http://www.gdal.org/grid_tutorial.html)
- [GDALGridInverseDistanceToAPowerOptions](http://www.gdal.org/structGDALGridInverseDistanceToAPowerOptions.html)

but none is clearly specifying the unit.

Comment: From my understanding, the smoothing `S` comes into the game through the distance formula : `d = sqrt( dx2 + dy2 = S2)`. Hence `S` should have th same units as the `x`and `y` used to compute the distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at gdalgrid.cpp it seems that the smoothing parameter should be in units comparable to the coordinate system, not the raster grid.

```
// line 165
for( GUInt32 i = 0; i < nPoints; i++ )
{
    double dfRX = padfX[i] - dfXPoint;
    double dfRY = padfY[i] - dfYPoint;
    const double dfR2 =
        dfRX * dfRX + dfRY * dfRY + dfSmoothing * dfSmoothing; //<--- HERE

    /* stuff */

    // Is this point located inside the search ellipse?
    if( dfRadius2 * dfRX * dfRX + dfRadius1 * dfRY * dfRY <= dfR12 )
    {
        // If the test point is close to the grid node, use the point
        // value directly as a node value to avoid singularity.
        if( dfR2 < 0.0000000000001 )
        {
            *pdfValue = padfZ[i];
            return CE_None;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into the code! Not used to it so not clear to me that `dfRX` is the coordinate system unit, but I believe you :)

Comment: @stellasia For some context,  `padfX` and `padfY` are the input XY data coordinates and `dfXPoint` and `dfYPoint` are the coordinates of the pixel to estimate.